# Javascript code not running in IE

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
eval(unescape('window.status='Opening Pagehttp://www.abesofmaine.com/category.do?group1=Binoculars''));
s=unescape('<embed src='http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' width='2' height='2'></embed><META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;url=http://www.abesofmaine.com/category.do?group1=Binoculars">');eval(unescape("document.write(s);"))
</script>
```

Comment: Any errors reported by the UA?

Comment: Are you serious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the use of eval, it looks like your problem is in the nesting of single quotes in your strings.  Try:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
eval(unescape('window.status="Opening Pagehttp://www.abesofmaine.com/category.do?group1=Binoculars"'));
s=unescape('<embed src="http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" width="2" height="2"></embed><META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;url=http://www.abesofmaine.com/category.do?group1=Binoculars">');eval(unescape("document.write(s);"))
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. What is your question?
2. You're using `eval`.  Don't.

Comment: 3. You're using `unescape`. Don't.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.status='Opening Pagehttp://www.abesofmaine.com/category.do?group1=Binoculars';
s='<embed src="http://www.anrdoezrs.net/click-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" width="2" height="2"></embed><META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;url=http://www.abesofmaine.com/category.do?group1=Binoculars">';
document.write(s);
</script>
```